# Generics in Java, returning a set of a generic class Set<T>

Tags: java, class, generics

So I have this code, I'm trying to return a set of a class that is extending another class

```
public static <T> Set<T> getClassesExtending(Class<T> clazz) {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("");
    Set<Class<? extends T>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(clazz);

    if (classes.size() <= 0) return new HashSet<>();

    Set<T> extending = classes.stream().filter(c -> c instanceof T).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return extending;
}
```

Issue:

```
c instanceof T //shows compile error 'Class or array expected' above 'T'
```

So for example, if I were to write...

```
getClassesExtending(MyClass.class).forEach(c -> c.methodInMyClass())
```

it would work. Any advice?

Comment: Just use `filter(clazz::isInstance)`

Comment: How can you get a `Set<T>` from a `Stream<Class<? extends T>>`?

Comment: Tried `filter(clazz::isInstance)` but it showed this error "Incompatible types. Required Set<T> but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Class<? extends T> conforms to T inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: T lower bounds: Class<? extends T>"

Comment: In `filter(c -> c instanceof T)`, the argument `c` is of type `Class<? extends T>` and therefore can never be an `instanceof T`, as the class `Class` is not derived from T.

Comment: Also @Eran, if I have a class B that extends a class A, I want to be able to get a set of A. This is why I want help I'm not to sure how to do this really

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Ah I see... so what would be a work around ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a set of A"; only a set of *instances* of A. Where are you going to find instances? Use Malt's answer and note the return type.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Well, presumably with reflection. If the class (instance) extends A, that's an instance of A, so why cant I use that somehow? I just dont know how? Also what answer?

Comment: Generics is a compile time thing, when the compiler compiles the source code, it replaces all generic types with their upper bound (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) which is Object if there is no upper bound. So even if the code compiled, there would still have been a bug in you code. Although it makes me wonder why `c instanceOf T` throws a compile time error.

Comment: The `getSubTypesOf` method returns instances of class `java.lang.Class` which is totally different to an instance of the class you're looking for. You don't have any instances of `A`, you only have instances of `Class<A>` and those instances are not related to class A.

Comment: It's not really clear for me what you want to do. Say for instance, I can't find a class called `Reflections` (mind the **s**). It would be great if you could provide some input - expected output pairs.

Comment: @TamasRev Reflections is an Open Source class at https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Comment: @Realmm re "Also what answer?" A user named Malt had an answer when I wrote my above comment. I thought it was a good and correct answer, but unfortunately he's since deleted it.

Comment: If you're trying to check whether one `Class` is a subclass of another, you can do `clazz::isAssignableFrom`. But I don't see the point of filtering if you've already requested subtypes of `clazz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, from the way you want to use it as you described, you want to

  - find the classes extending a class `clazz`
  - create their objects using their default constructors and then
  - call methods on them.

This code should get your job done

```
public static <T> Set<? extends T> getClassesExtending(Class<T> clazz) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("");
        Set<Class<? extends T>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(clazz);

        if (classes.size() <= 0) return new HashSet<>();

        Set<? extends T> extending =
                classes.stream().map(aClass -> {
                    try {
                        return aClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
         return extending;
    }
```

I'd suggest you throw in a `filter()` operation to filter out any subclasses without a no-arg constructor to prevent `null`s in the `extending` set.

- Secondly, when you did this

  `Set<T> extending = classes.stream().filter(c -> c instanceof T).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

If you were actually trying to filter the set into classes, the operation would have been idempotent, that is it would produce no change in the set.

Finally, the reason why `c instanceof T` causes a compilation error is because `instanceOf` operator does not allow non-refiable types on its rhs and generic types are non-refiable. ([JLS 11 section: 15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/jls11.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that `T` is erased in run-time.

You can try this:

```
Set<T> extending = classes.stream().filter(c -> c.isAssignableFrom(clazz)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: `c` is already a `Class`. So `c.getClass()` would return `java.lang.Class.class`.

Comment: @Realmm fixed that, also fixed problem DodgyCodeException mention.